# Send a message to all clients in a Group, except for the current client

Tags: signalr

I want to execute a method on all connected clients from the server, except for the current client. Any way to do this without me maintaining my own list of clientids?

TIA!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use **Clients.OthersInGroup()** method.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality has been proposed and discussed on the github issues list for the project, but is not yet implemented http://goo.gl/pyMwF.

For now, you will need to do your own filtering of your clients.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.
For now I just set a variable on the caller Caller.IgnoreMethod1 = true; and use that value to filter the method call on the client side. Not very efficient, but it'll do for now as I'm trying to avoid keeping a separate list of clients/groups.